# how to retain api gateway stage on AWS SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I have template.yaml this code
Make api gateway and some function

```
  GatewayAPI:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: !Ref StageName
      OpenApiVersion: '2.0'
      Name: !Sub 'api-${ProjectName}'
```

```
  DeviceFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      MemorySize: 512
      FunctionName: ....
      CodeUri: src/
      Handler: handlers/....
      Events:
        HBNDeviceGet:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /devices
            Method: GET
            RestApiId:
              Ref: GatewayAPI
```

first deploy StageName = dev
second deploy StageName = release

I want have two stage (dev, release)

but AWS SAM was delete existing stage (dev) and create release stage

how to deploy new stage without deletion dev stage?